# Web browsers missing characters

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, upgrade, character-encoding, browser

I regularly update my Linux system (mint 19.1 Tessa). After a recent update many of the websites I visit appear to have missing characters, at least visually.

I've tried on Firefox and Chromium based browsers and all of them have the same problem, hence I suspect its a Linux system problem and not the browsers.

I've tried installing transitional font packages from Synaptic to no avail.

But installing an outdated version of Firefox seems to fix the problem, though its not really a solution for me.

Any pointers will be welcome.

Edit 1:
Clearing browser cache has no effect; characters are still missing on affected sites.
Running websites on localhost works fine.

[image]

Comment: web pages don't have to use your local font but often they use font downloaded from own server or from servers which offer fonts - like [Google Font](https://fonts.google.com/. And they may download it everytime when you visit page or browser may keep font in cache. I don't know if it would help to clear cache. OR maybe try in `private mode` - it should not keep data in cache - maybe it confirm (or not) that it can be problem with cache.

Comment: what if you create HTML/text file and open in web browser ? Do you still have missing chars?

Comment: Clearing browser cache has no effect; characters are still missing on affected sites. Running websites on localhost works fine.

Comment: I have no idea. This element use fonts `Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif` which you could reinstall with [How can I install Segoe UI font?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370890/how-can-i-install-segoe-ui-font) but it doesn't explain why it works in older version. Maybe you should send it to `Mozilla`/`Firefox` authors. Or wait for newer version - maybe it will works better. [Firefox Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/firefox)